# Чому вживаємо давальний відмінок у "нема кому [щось зробити]"

Tags: граматика, non-native-speaker

З Шевченкового "Не хочу я женитися":

**Нема кому привітати**,

Ні з ким пожуритись,

Треба було б молодому,

Треба б одружитись.

Минулися молодії

Веселії літа,

Немає з ким ости[г]лого

Серденька нагріти.

**Нема кому зострінути**,

Затопити хату,

**Нема кому** води тії

Каліці **подати**.

Чому в цьому випадку вживається давальний відмінок? Яке походження цієї фрази?

Це питання мені задала людина, яка вивчає українську мову як іноземну.
Я не зміг відповісти сам, тому прошу допомоги.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Це стосується не лише негативних формулювань («нема/немає кому»), а й позитивних («було/є/буде кому»):

> — Робіть що знаєте, аби б біля мене були, щоб **було кому** мене при смерті доглядіти. // Григорій Квітка-Основ'яненко, «Козир-дівка», 1838.

Гарне запитання. А й справді, тут логічніші були б називний і родовий (і так, звісно, теж кажуть): «є той, хто <щось робив би>» і «нема того, хто <щось робив би>» («хто» завжди в називному, а відмінок «той/того» залежить від «є» чи «нема»). Ми навіть маємо через це омонімію, наприклад «нема кому написати листа»: «нема того, хто написав би» чи «нема того, хто прочитав би»?

Чесно, я не знаю справжньої відповіді, але, може, тут семантика **вручення завдання, давання ролі, призначення функції**, мовляв: «нема кому [призначити функцію] привітати», «нема кому [призначити функцію] зострінути», «нема кому [призначити функцію] подати каліці воду».

Кажуть же, наприклад, «мені є що робити» («мені» у давальному відмінку) або «от кому тепер прибирати після тебе?» («кому» у давальному відмінку) — мені здається, це той самий мотив призначення функції.

У [СУМ-20](https://sum20ua.com/Entry/index?wordid=6191&page=226) для «бути» є щось подібне про «діставатися, випадати на долю», але там радше акцент на покарання, ніж на завдання/роль/функцію:

> Якби ти знала, що **мені** вчора **було** за те, що з тобою ходила гойдатися до Ривки… (Леся Українка)
>
> **Було їй** уже за той модний передчасний хвіст [зачіску], критикували на шкільних… зборах (О. Гончар).

Загалом я бачу, що давальний відмінок використовується доволі широко, наприклад «мені холодно» («мені байдуже») — тут комусь дістається навіть не завдання чи покарання, а просто стан.

Грубо підсумовуючи — у давальному відмінку стоїть той, хто щось отримує, але:

- отримує необов'язково від конкретної людини, може отримувати невідомо від кого або «від всесвіту»;
- отримує необов'язково щось конкретне, може отримувати щось абстрактне/уявне;
- отримуване необов'язково загальновизнане/постійне, це може бути й щось, що існує суто один момент в уяві мовця.